# Unable to process binding foreach with cannot read property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

my entire code works well before I added remove functionality to this demo code.
Although I am calling this binding with `$root` but it is giving the same error. 
I am also attaching the screenshot of the error I get.

```
 //my product class
          function Product(name, price) {

                this.name = ko.observable(name);
                this.price = ko.observable(price);

            };

    //my observable array
            this.shoppingCart = ko.observableArray([

                new Product("milk", 10.99),
                new Product("bread", 7.99),
                new Product("Jam",1.39)

            ]);       


    //below is my view model

            function personViewModel() {
                var self = this;

                firstName= ko.observable("John");
                lastName = ko.observable("Smith");
                checkOut = function () {
                    alert("Trying to Checkout");
                };

                fullName = ko.computed(function () {
                    return firstName() + " " + lastName();
                })

                this.addProduct = function () {

                    self.shoppingCart.push(new Product("Yogurt", 10.99));

                };

              //this method is bind with the button and producing error
                this.removeProduct = function (product) {
                    self.shoppingCart.remove(product)
                };

            };
            ko.applyBindings(personViewModel);

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, Knockout.js</h1>
        <p><span data-bind='text: fullName'></span>'s Shopping cart</p>
        <button data-bind="click: checkOut">Checkout</button>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: shoppingCart">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text:price"></td>

                  <!--below binding is breaking the script-->

                    <td><button data-bind="click: $root.removeProduct">Remove</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button data-bind="click: addProduct">Add Item</button>
    </body>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: You are missing a `new` in the statement: `ko.applyBindings(personViewModel);` should be `ko.applyBindings(new personViewModel);`

Comment: @nemesv if i comment the removeProduct function and $root.removeProduct binding i am able to add products to my cart. I tried ko.applyBindings(new personViewModel); only thing i got is my entire list of product on the view but i am not able to add and remove the products and the changed error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined".

Comment: Your code is pretty messed up: you are not consistently using `this`  and `self` and you are missing them from a few places which results in globally defined objects, etc. Here is a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/y7wrjywn/

Comment: @satyanshu It may help if you can transform your question into a [Stack Snippet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  It has native support for knockout examples

Comment: @nemsev yea that works. thanks ! If ayou can clarify why did you took the observable array inside the view model.

Comment: @nemsev yea that works. thanks ! If you can clarify why you took the observable array inside the view model. I tried keeping the functions out of the view model with the observable array and it just worked as expected what is the difference here ? here is another working code http://jsfiddle.net/satyanshua/eawd9y06/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the error was due to the scope of the functions and the observable array.

Binding is not able to locate the corresponding view model object.

Below are two solutions for this. Please checkout these JS fiddles.

`jsfiddle.net/y7wrjywn` in which the observable array is taken inside the view model definition.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<body>
     <h1>Hello, Knockout.js</h1>

    <p><span data-bind='text: fullName'></span>'s Shopping cart</p>
    <button data-bind="click: checkOut">Checkout</button>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: shoppingCart">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text:price"></td>
                <!--below binding is breaking the script-->
                <td>
                    <button data-bind="click: $root.removeProduct">Remove</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button data-bind="click: addProduct">Add Item</button>
</body>

//the script

         function Product(name, price) {

             this.name = ko.observable(name);
             this.price = ko.observable(price);

         };

         function personViewModel() {
             var self = this;

             self.firstName = ko.observable("John");
             self.lastName = ko.observable("Smith");
             self.checkOut = function () {
                 alert("Trying to Checkout");
             };

             self.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
                 return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
             })

             self.addProduct = function () {

                 self.shoppingCart.push(new Product("Yogurt", 10.99));

             };

             self.shoppingCart = ko.observableArray([

             new Product("milk", 10.99),
             new Product("bread", 7.99),
             new Product("Jam", 1.39)

             ]);


             //this method is bind with the button and producing error
             self.removeProduct = function (product) {
                 self.shoppingCart.remove(product)
             };

         };

         ko.applyBindings(new personViewModel);
```

`http://jsfiddle.net/satyanshua/eawd9y06/1/` in which the functions are taken out of the viewmodel

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<body>
     <h1>Hello, Knockout.js</h1>

    <p><span data-bind='text: fullName'></span>'s Shopping cart</p>
    <button data-bind="click: checkOut">Checkout</button>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: shoppingCart">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text:price"></td>
                <td>
                    <button data-bind="click: removeProduct">Remove</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button data-bind="click: addProduct">Add Item</button>
</body>


function Product(name, price) {

    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.price = ko.observable(price);

}

shoppingCart = ko.observableArray([

new Product("milk", 10.99),
new Product("bread", 7.99),
new Product("Jam", 1.39)

]);

addProduct = function () {

    shoppingCart.push(new Product("Yogurt", 10.99));

};

self.removeProduct = function (product) {
    shoppingCart.remove(product);
};


function personViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    firstName = ko.observable("John");
    lastName = ko.observable("Smith");
    checkOut = function () {
        alert("Trying to Checkout");
    };

    fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return firstName() + " " + lastName();
    });


}
ko.applyBindings(new personViewModel());
```